# How to make faster search result?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search-engine

I using people search code it's working but i'm get search result it's very slow hopefully someone here can do better than me please give feedback. i'll attached the code down.

**this is Javascript code.**

```
<script>
    function lightbg_clr() {
        $('#qu').val("");
        $('#textbox-clr').text("");
        // $('#search-layer').css({"width":"30%"});
        // $('#livesearch').css({"display":"none"});
        $("#qu").focus();
    };

    function fx(str)
    {
        var s1=document.getElementById("qu").value;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (str.length==0) {
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
            // document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
            // document.getElementById("search-layer").style.width="auto";
            // document.getElementById("search-layer").style.height="auto";
            // document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display="block";
            $('#textbox-clr').text("");
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                // document.getElementById("search-layer").style.width="50%";
                // document.getElementById("search-layer").style.height="50%";
                // document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display="block";
                $('#textbox-clr').text("X");
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../validate/call_ajax.php?n="+s1,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

**This is my HTML code**

```
<div class="bk">
<input type="text" onKeyUp="fx(this.value)" autocomplete="on" name="qu" id="qu" class="textbox" placeholder="What are you looking for ?" tabindex="1">
<button type="submit" class="query-submit" tabindex="2"><i class="fa fa-search" style="color:#001150; font-size:20px"></i></button>
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</div>
```

**This is fetching PHP code**

Here i'm using database and fetching data form two different table with same user ID

```
<?php
include('../db/mySqlDBi.class.php');
$dbConn = new mySqlDB();

$s1=$_REQUEST["n"];

$select_query=
    "SELECT * 
      FROM u_info_one as uio, u_info_two as uit 
      WHERE
        uio.u_id=uit.u_id 
        AND u_fname LIKE '%".$s1."%' 
        AND uio.`u_id`!='{$_SESSION["u_id"]}' 
        AND `u_flag`!='0'";
$sql=$dbConn->selector($select_query);
$s="";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $s=$s."
    <a class='link-p-colr' href='user-profile.php?user_id=".$row['u_id']."'>
        <div class='live-outer'>
                <div class='live-im'>";

                        if($row['u_image']!="") {

                       $s=$s."<img src='".$row['u_image']."' alt=\"\">";

                        }else {
                                $s=$s."<img src=\"../images/male-avatar1.png\" alt=\"\">";
                        }

    $s=$s."</div>
                <div class='live-product-det'>
                    <div class='live-product-name'>
                        <p>".$row['u_fname']." ".$row['u_lname']."</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    ";
}
echo $s;
?>
```

Comment: You will not succeed to implement a well performing search engine based on using a `%LIKE%` clause in your sql query. That is not how search engines are built exactly because that is slow like chewing gum. Read a bit about search engines. They all do pre processing: they store all separated words from input stored inside the database in some additional "index" table adding a back reference to the original stored string. That way you can search using an equals operator in an indexed table of words which is very fast and you receive back the references to the strings holding those words.

Comment: Maybe you should also consider to have a look at [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/de/) which are in my experience *much* faster and come with other great features like e.g. facets and suggestions ("did you mean ..."). There are already modules existing for some CMS/Shop systems making it rel. easy to put them to work.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @arkascha : using LIKE is not good for performance... That being said, here are a few possible optimizations for your use case.

**1) Use real JOINs**

```
FROM u_info_one as uio, u_info_two as uit 
 WHERE
     uio.u_id=uit.u_id
```

You want to use JOINs instead of old style cross JOINs with a WHERE clause ; depending on your RDBMS and data, this might perform better.

**2) Use relevant data types**

```
AND `u_flag`!='0'
```

You are comparing strings, but it looks like u_flag should be a numeric field, maybe a TINYINT(1). Smaller datatypes make faster searches, and comparing numbers is usually more efficient than strings. Check the definition of this field in your table.

**3) Index your search criterias**

You want an index on columns being searched in both table. I cannot tell exactly which columns belong to which table as not all your identifiers are quoted, but one (maybe composite) index per table should be fine, like :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_info_one ON info_one(u_fname, u_flag);
```

Here is your updated query :

```
$select_query=
    "SELECT * 
      FROM 
          u_info_one as uio
          INNER JOIN u_info_two as uit 
              ON uio.u_id=uit.u_id
      WHERE
        u_fname LIKE '%".$s1."%' 
        AND uio.`u_id`!='{$_SESSION["u_id"]}' 
        AND `u_flag`!=0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all database fields your searching in properly indexed?

Do you really need both data sets (assoc and numbered). If not switch to assoc only.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)
```

Could you use a JOIN instead of both 2 tables

```
SELECT * 
FROM u_info_one as uio
LEFT JOIN u_info_two as uit
ON (uio.u_id = uit.u_id) 
WHERE
    u_fname LIKE '%".$s1."%' 
    AND uio.`u_id`!='{$_SESSION["u_id"]}' 
    AND `u_flag`!='0'
```

And if you don't need all fields SELECT only the fields you need.